# How to control the creation order of fork()?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pid

The problem is to create a tree of processes using C's fork() on Linux in this alphabetical order:

```
A: B, C, D
-B: E, F
-C: G
--G: I
-D:
```

[Required tree of processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f2ue.png)

Currently, by using if, I could see abcdeGFi by observing PIDs in htop, not the correct order.

[Results observed using htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FufGs.png)

Seeing C's PID is (currently) always B's PID + 1, so I tried to patch by STOP-ing C before forking B and CONT-ing C afterwards:

```
    int b = getpid();
    kill(b + 1, SIGSTOP);
    fork(); /* E created */
    if (getpid() == b) {
        fork(); /* F created */
    }
    kill(b + 1, SIGCONT);
```

This gives the right order, however, it is ugly and prone to error if C isn't next to B, is there a flawless way to create processes in that order?

Comment: You'd have to use a synchronization mechanism (e.g. mutex). (Note that not all kernels use continuously ascending PIDs. And even if yours does, your plan will fail if when PIDs wrap around.)

Comment: If you decide to use a mutex, be wary each process might end up with a copy of the mutex. You might want to consider a process-shared semaphore.

Comment: @Dan Le - To enable others to find the flaw in your _way to create processes in that order_, you should show how you do it.

Comment: @Armali. Just naive forking with no synchronization. Having an minimal runable demonstration would allow others to add a solution to it without having to waste as much of their time, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly.

- You want to prevent *B* from creating *E* and *F* until *D* is created by *A*.
- You want to prevent *C* from creating *G* until *F* is created by *B*.

That means

- *B* must wait for a message from *D* or *A* (indicating *D* was created) before creating *E* and *F*.
- *C* must wait for a message from *F* or *B* (indicating *F* was created) before creating *G*.

The word message is used very loosely here. I mean some form of information transfer.

A pipe could be used effectively here. Say that *R* (receiver) needs to wait for *S* (sender) to be created.

- Have *S* close the write end of the pipe.
- Have *R* wait for EOF before proceeding.

There are two circumstances under which *R* will proceed:

- *S* was created.
- *S* will never be created (because of a crash or something).

So, this approach is "crash-proof", meaning you won't have processes waiting forever if things go wrong. And if you so desired, you could even distinguish the circumstances by having *S* send a byte before closing the pipe. Perfect.

It just becomes a question of closing the pipes handles at the right time. The following is a demonstration of your goal achieved. (It's written in Perl, but `pipe`, `fork`, `waitpid`, `sleep` and `close` are just thin wrappers for the C functions with the same name. Just ignore the `$`.)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub fork_child {
   my $sub = shift;

   my $pid = fork();
   if (!$pid) {
      if (!eval { $sub->(@_); 1 }) {
         warn( eval { "$@" } // "Unknown error" );
         exit(($? >> 8) || $! || 255);
      }

      exit(0);
   }

   return $pid;
}

sub a {
   $0 = "a";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   pipe(my $d_created_recver, my $d_created_sender);
   pipe(my $f_created_recver, my $f_created_sender);

   my $pid_b = fork_child(\&b, $d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender);
   my $pid_c = fork_child(\&c, $d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender);
   my $pid_d = fork_child(\&d, $d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender);

   close($_) for $d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender;

   waitpid($pid_b, 0);
   waitpid($pid_c, 0);
   waitpid($pid_d, 0);
}

sub b {
   my ($d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender) = @_;

   $0 = "b";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   # Not related to B or its descendants.
   close($_) for $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver;

   # Wait for D to be created.
   read($d_created_recver, my $buf, 1);
   close($d_created_recver);

   my $pid_e = fork_child(\&e, $f_created_sender);
   my $pid_f = fork_child(\&f, $f_created_sender);

   # Allow G to be created.
   close($f_created_sender);

   waitpid($pid_e, 0);
   waitpid($pid_f, 0);
}

sub c {
   my ($d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender) = @_;

   $0 = "c";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   # Not related to C or its descendants.
   close($_) for $d_created_sender, $d_created_recver, $f_created_sender;

   # Wait for F to be created.
   read($f_created_recver, my $buf, 1);
   close($f_created_recver);

   my $pid_g = fork_child(\&g);

   waitpid($pid_g, 0);
}

sub d {
   my ($d_created_recver, $d_created_sender, $f_created_recver, $f_created_sender) = @_;

   $0 = "d";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   # Not related to D or its descendants.
   close($_) for $d_created_recver, $f_created_sender, $f_created_recver;

   # Allow E to be created.
   close($d_created_sender);

   sleep();
}

sub e {
   my ($f_created_sender) = @_;

   $0 = "e";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   # Not related to E process or its decendants.
   close($f_created_sender);

   sleep();
}

sub f {
   my ($f_created_sender) = @_;

   $0 = "f";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   # Allow G to be created.
   close($f_created_sender);

   sleep();
}

sub g {
   $0 = "g";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   my $pid_i = fork_child(\&i);

   waitpid($pid_i, 0);
}

sub i {
   $0 = "i";
   say "$0 is pid $$";

   sleep();
}

a();
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for your dedication! Although the length of your answer scares me, I will come back after learning more about semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

I endorse ikegami's analysis of the required holding points and information transfers. Here's an example (omitting error checks) using semaphores in C:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

int main()
{   // Create set of 2 semaphores; Linux initializes the values to 0.
    int ss = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2, 0600);
    pid_t B, C, D, E, F, G, I;                      // the child processes
    if ((B = fork()) == 0)
    {   // wait for semaphore number 0 (D)
        semop(ss, &(struct sembuf){.sem_num=0, .sem_op=-1}, 1);
        if ((E = fork()) == 0) return sleep(9);     // E stay for a while
        if ((F = fork()) == 0)
        {   // C may now start G - unlock semaphore number 1
            semop(ss, &(struct sembuf){.sem_num=1, .sem_op=+1}, 1);
            return sleep(9);                        // F stay for a while
        }
        return sleep(9);                            // B stay for a while
    }
    if ((C = fork()) == 0)
    {   // wait for semaphore number 1 (F)
        semop(ss, &(struct sembuf){.sem_num=1, .sem_op=-1}, 1);
        if ((G = fork()) == 0)
        {
            if ((I = fork()) == 0) return sleep(9); // I stay for a while
            return sleep(9);                        // G stay for a while
        }
        return sleep(9);                            // C stay for a while
    }
    if ((D = fork()) == 0)
    {   // B may now start E, F - unlock semaphore number 0
        semop(ss, &(struct sembuf){.sem_num=0, .sem_op=+1}, 1);
        return sleep(9);                            // D stay for a while
    }
    sleep(9);                                       // A stay for a while
    semctl(ss, 0, IPC_RMID);                        // remove the semaphore set
}
```

Comment: This is a lot shorter than my solution, but it's not "crash-proof". (See my answer for what I mean by this.) This could be resolved by adding a timeout to the waits somehow.